AUC for Receiver Operating Characteristic
I saw this definition on the internet:
$
\text{AUROC} = \int_0^1 \text{TPR}(\text{FPR}) \, d(\text{FPR})
$
But I am not sure whether it is correct and how it should be interpreted, though the general ROC and the concept of AUC are intuitively clear to me. Here my thoughts:
I guess the Riemann-Stieltjes is used, because in principle it is not guaranteed that you have a differentiable curve. Thus we need the generalization, because partly we would want to sum the area, while the differentiable part can be calculated with the Riemann integral. But how to read this if we could simplify it to the Riemann integral? I guess you are integrating from 0 to 1 across the x-axis (FPR) and up the area under the TPR? But that is not very precise and I am not sure on how to simplify the formula such that one can see that.
